# Network scanner with Python

Tags: python, networking

I am trying to make a netscanner with python for linux but I've got some problems.

Here is the code

```
 import scapy.all as scapy
 import optparse

 def get_user_input():
    my_object = optparse.OptionParser
    my_object.add_option("-i","-ip", dest="ip_address",help="please type ip address")
 (user_inputs,arguments)=my_object.parse_args()
 return user_inputs

 def scan(ip):
    arp_packet = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    broadcast_packet = scapy.Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
     arp_and_broadcast_packet = broadcast_packet/arp_packet
     answered_list = scapy.srp(arp_and_broadcast_packet,timeout=1)
     answered_list.summary()

def result_scan(scan_list):
print("IP\t\t\tMAC\n-----------------------------------------------------")
for client in scan_list:
    print(client["ip"]+ "\t\t" + client["mac"])

 user_ip_address = get_user_input()
 scan_network = user_ip_address.ipaddress
```

Here is what problem I got:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Netscanner.py", line 23, in <module>
  user_ip_address = get_user_input()
  File "Netscanner.py", line 7, in get_user_input
  my_object.add_option("-i","-ip", dest="ip_address",help="please type ip address")
  TypeError: unbound method add_option() must be called with OptionParser instance as first 
  argument (got str instance instead)
```

Comment: Please include any code you're asking about in the question itself. If remote links change or expire the question becomes useless as a resource to future readers.

Comment: Just a suggestion, use another argument parser such as click or argparse instead of optparse, as it became deprecated after Python 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instantiate the `OptionParser` object (forgot to add brackets):

```
def get_user_input():
    my_object = optparse.OptionParser()
    my_object.add_option("-i", "--ip", dest="ip_address",help="please type ip address")

    ...
```

Also, you should pass the second argument as `--ip`.

Comment: Why its not giving me an output ? the error is fixed btw thanks

Comment: maybe, It's related to typo, (`ip_address` - missed underscore)

`scan_network = user_ip_address.ip_address`